# Throwing HTTP nest Exception results in Promise rejection

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to throw a http nest exception to make use of the default nest handler.

I Tried to throw the exception in the controller that calls the adminService.update function, and with great success it worked.

```js
  async update(update: DeepPartial<Admin>) {
    const admin = await this.findOne({ id: update.id});
    const adminName = await this.findOne({ username: update.username});
    if (!adminName) {
      throw new ConflictException('Username already in use');
    }
    admin.username = update.username;
    admin.save();
  }
```

Output when putting the call in the controller:

```
{
  "statusCode": 409,
  "error": "Conflict",
  "message": "Username already in use"
}
```

The controller method.

```js
  @Put()
  async update(@Body() updateDTO: UpdateDTO): Promise<void> {
    throw new ConflictException('Username already in use');
    this.adminService.update(updateDTO);
  }
```

The error itself:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [object Object] at AdminService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JBRETAS_EXT\Documents\mapa-digital\dist\admin\admin.service.js:55:19) at Generator.next (<anonymous>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I was missing a return statement in my controller method.

```js
  @Put()
  async update(@Body() updateDTO: UpdateDTO): Promise<void> {
    return this.adminService.update(updateDTO);
  }
```